# FlatList rendeItem component doesn't recognize `this` keyword

Tags: react-native, this, react-native-flatlist

I have to call a function inside the renderItem function that is called for each item in a FlatList's data. The function will come from the component it comes from and uses a little of the component's state, however, it always returns an error that the method is undefined when it comes to getting that method or, for that matter, the data in the component's state.

Here's the method and how the FlatList looks like

```
  renderItem({ item, index }) {    
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.goToStaffMemberPage(item.id)} }>
        <View style={GenericStyles.styles.genericCard}>
          <Text style={GenericStyles.styles.genericCardTitle}> {item.first_name.toUpperCase() + " " + item.last_name.toUpperCase()} </Text>
          <Text style={GenericStyles.styles.genericCardDescription}> {item.role_name.toUpperCase()} </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

```
<FlatList
 data={this.state.staffList}
 keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
 renderItem={this.renderItem}
 contentContainerStyle={GenericStyles.styles.genericContainer}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are not giving it access to `this`. You can either bind it (preferability in the `constructor`) doing:

```
constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.renderItem.bind(this);
}
```

or using arrow function directly when you define renderItem:

```
renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {    
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.goToStaffMemberPage(item.id)} }>
        <View style={GenericStyles.styles.genericCard}>
          <Text style={GenericStyles.styles.genericCardTitle}> {item.first_name.toUpperCase() + " " + item.last_name.toUpperCase()} </Text>
          <Text style={GenericStyles.styles.genericCardDescription}> {item.role_name.toUpperCase()} </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hey , i have a flatlist and the data come from firebase DB and it's work perfectly but when i delete an item from DB so should i see what's happening in flatList so every single item deleted very well but last item in the array when i deleted them from DB Flatlist can't rerender and delete it just stuck in the screen , but when i reload the app i cant see it ! So how can i handle it to force Flatlist to re-render?